# Require bash script to be run with sudo (not as root user)?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, bash-scripting, su

I want to require a bash script to be run as the current user with `sudo`, but prevent it from being run if it was executed as the root user directly.  This is because I'm doing some setup actions for the current user that require root permissions, but depend on the `SUDO_USER` environment variable being set.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Require script to be run via sudo, but not as root

if [[ $EUID != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Script must be run with root privilages!"
    exit 1
elif [[ $EUID = $UID && "$SUDO_USER" = "" ]]; then
    echo "Script must be run as current user via 'sudo', not as the root user!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Is this reliable as it stands?  I'm a bit unsure about my checking if `EUID` and `UID` match, since I don't know if `UID` is always reliably set correctly.  Would it be simply enough to check if `SUDO_USER` is empty?

Comment: It is possible for users or programs other than sudo to set the variable "$SUDO_USER", so that isn't a secure / reliable test.  I would suggest warnings rather than trying to enforce it, particularly if you're doing it a script that your users can read.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it wouldn't be enough, because anyone can use sudo to user other than root:

```
[my.username@some_hostname ~]$ echo "'$SUDO_USER':'$UID':'$EUID'"
'':'503':'503'
[my.username@some_hostname ~]$ sudo -i -u zenoss
[zenoss@some_hostname ~]$ echo "'$SUDO_USER':'$UID':'$EUID'"
'my.username':'1337':'1337'
```

(CentOS 6.5, GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

I understand your opinion about UID/EUID, but I'd probably stick to $UID alone. Unfortunately even 'bash info' is not especially verbose, but [one revered source](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#UIDREF) says:

```
$UID
    User ID number
    Current user's user identification number, as recorded in /etc/passwd
    This is the current user's real id, even if she has temporarily assumed another
    identity through su. $UID is a readonly variable, not subject to change from 
    the command line or within a script, and is the counterpart to the id builtin.

$EUID
    "effective" user ID number
    Identification number of whatever identity the current user has assumed, 
    perhaps by means of su.
    Caution 
        The $EUID is not necessarily the same as the $UID.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ID=`id -u`
if [ $ID -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "This command must be run as root."
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You seem to miss the point. Please read the question carefully again. It is about "I'm *the* root" vs. "I'm not really the root, just using `sudo`". Your code cannot tell it apart.